# How do I improve this email address validation method?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form called sub_form with 2 inputs, one of the inputs is an email address, the other is a choice from a dropdown menu. The Javascript below checks if the email address is valid, and also prints the values of both the inputs to the console log.

The problem is, when an incorrect email is entered, it shows the error message but still prints to the console.

How can I fix this so that the inputs only print to console if a valid email is entered?

```js
<!-- validator -->
$('#sub_form').bootstrapValidator({live: 'disabled',
 fields: {
 email: {
  validators: {
   emailAddress: {
     message: 'Invalid email' } }},}});

<!--print to console-->
document.getElementById('sub_form').onsubmit = function(){
       console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
       console.log(document.getElementById('dropdown').value);
       return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, which validator plugin and version are you using? Could you provide a link to the plugin repo/homepage? I've found several bootstrap validators, but can't seem to find one matching the API you are using.

Comment: Hi, I used the validator from here:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/contact-us-form-with-validation

Comment: This validator plugin is an older version of the one found at http://formvalidation.io/.  The API is largely the same with a couple of changes: the object name is "bootstrapValidator" instead of "formValidation", and the event namespace uses "bv" instead of "fv".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment on the question, this validation library as far as I've been able to tell is an older version of the one [here](http://formvalidation.io).  My company happens to use the same one, so I've been using that site a lot for reference.  Just replace mentions of the "formValidation" method with "bootstrapValidator", and events use the "bv" namespace instead of "fv".

The validator should provide some methods for checking its valid state.  You could use:

```
var validator = $('#sub_form').data('bootstrapValidator');
if (validator.isValidField('email')) {
  console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
}
```

See [here](http://formvalidation.io/api/#is-valid-field) for more info.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get to this earlier but thank you! Your link was helpful :)